# Using Python 3, how to print a panda series with categories

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How do I print the car_data Series using Python 3?

```
import pandas as pd

car_colors = pd.Series(['Blue', 'Red', 'Green'], dtype='category')

car_data = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(['Yellow', 'Green', 'Red', 'Blue', Purple'], categories=car_colors, ordered=False))

print(str(car_colors)) # works

# both print statements below give this error:
# ValueError: object __array_method not producing an array
print(str(car_data)) 
print(car_data.to_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this, [`pd.Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas.Categorical), category takes and index-like values

```
car_colors = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']

car_data = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(['Yellow', 'Green', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Purple'], categories=car_colors, ordered=False))

print(str(car_colors)) # works
#Works now too....
print(str(car_data)) 
print(car_data.to_string())
```

Output:

```
['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']
0      NaN
1    Green
2      Red
3     Blue
4      NaN
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [Blue, Red, Green]
0      NaN
1    Green
2      Red
3     Blue
4      NaN
Categories (3, object): [Blue, Red, Green]
```